# Can a JPEG2000 file have multiple fragment list box?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg, codec, image-compression, jpeg2000

According to specification, The Fragment List box specifies the location, length and order of each of the fragments that, once combined, form a valid
and complete data stream.

I want to know can single JPEG2000 file have multiple fragment list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Fragment table contains the location, length and order of the fragments needed to recontruct ***one codestream***. Within a JPX file, you can include more than one codestream so, yes, you can have more than one fragment tables.

From section M.11.3 of the JPEG 2000 Part 2 standard,

> **M.11.3 Fragment Table box (superbox)**
>
> A Fragment Table box specifies the location of one of the codestreams in a JPX file. A file may contain zero or more
>   Fragment Table boxes. For the purpose of numbering codestreams, the Fragment Table box shall be considered
>   equivalent to a Contiguous Codestream box. Fragment Table boxes shall be found only at the top level of the file; they
>   shall not be found within a superbox.

However, I don't think you can have more than one table for a single codestream.

Comment: Can a single fragment table box have multiple fragment list boxes?

Comment: The standard says (M.11.3.1) that "The Fragment List box specifies the location, length and order of each of the fragments". My interpretation is that only one table should be present and contain references to all the fragments.